# Determinant of a binary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

So I've been trying a problem and I have reduced it to showing that the determinant of some binary matrix (the matrix filled with entries $0$ and $1$) is not equal to zero. I don't really know linear algebra so any help would be appreciated!

Also, in the problem that I am working on only has at-most two entries common in each row and there is atleast $3$ non zero entries in each row. That is, one row has atmost two entries in common in each rows. Also note that the order of matrix $\geq4.$

Comment: There isn't enough information here to describe how to answer. There are lots of binary matrices that have zero determinant.

Comment: This particular matrix has at-most two elements in common with each row and has at least 3 non zero elements, is there anything special that we can say about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "at-most two elements in common with each row"? An example or two of matrices that satisfy your conditions would be useful.

Comment: Take a $4\times4$ matrix

\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}

Two rows $R_1$ and $R_2$, share the same elements in 3rd and 4th entry, thats two elements common. Similarly $R_2$ and $R_3$ share same elements in 2nd and 3rd and so on